# Android java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with native library

Tags: java, android, gradle, java-native-interface, native-code

I tried to use some native library and received some Exception with underlying exception UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load viblast: findLibrary returned null
```

I am using Android Studio + gradle.
It looks like android can't find the native library in APK file.

My projects tree:

[image: file tree]

I tried to put them in "jniLibs" directory, but it doesn't helped me. I think I forget to write something in gradle files, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Are you using the *experimental* plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Create Folder "jniLibs" inside your "src/main/" and put all your .so files inside "src/main/jniLibs" folder. In your screenshot I can't find "jniLibs".

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps :

1. Add the path of your NDK in the  local.properties file, located to
   the root directory of your project.
2. add these lines to your app build.grade files  :

   sourceSets {
       main {
            jni.srcDirs = ["libs"]
            }
          }
3. Remove old .so files from your app.
4. Go to the directory src/jni directory of your app project and run the command :

> PATH_TO_YOUR_NDK/ndk-build

The project is compiling and your get your lib (.so) under the directory libs of your modules.

5.the libraries into your main app should be like below structure.

[image]

Please for reference visit [this](http://blog.guillaumeagis.eu/setup-andengine-with-android-studio/) link..!!

Thanks..!!